# Select lines with two occurences of same pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have several lines of output, some lines contain information on jobs waiting
example
I want to select lines that have more than one occurrence of the pattern
`jobs waiting: 0`

example:

```
abcdef rglk,jobs waiting: 2,blah,blah,jobs waiting:0,jobs running: 1,blah,blah
lbf(kjn fk)kkj,jobs waiting: 2,blah,blah,jobs running: 1,blah,blah
gdjhgvdjh,jobs waiting: 0,blah,blah,jobs running: 1,blah,blah,jobs waiting: 0
g gg,jobs waiting: 2,blah,jobs waiting: 0,jobs running: 1,blah,blah
kjn dikfc,jobs waiting: 0,blah,jobs waiting: 0,jobs running: 1,bl ah,blah
d1d,jobs waiting: 2,blah,blah,jobs running: 1,blah,blah
kjfdk nrf(lkj rgf),jobs waiting: 2,blah,blah,jobs waiting: 0,bl ah,blah
```

would work if the command only returns line 3 and line 5
I would also like to be able to select lines that are opposite to this
Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this, with sed? awk? grep?

Answer (score 2):

KISS `grep` approach:

```
grep 'jobs waiting: *0.*jobs waiting: *0' file
```

Invert by adding the `-v` command line switch.

Alternate with `sed` - attempt to replace the second instance, and print the line if it succeeds:

```
sed -n 's/jobs waiting: *0/&/2p' file
```

Inverse as

```
sed -n 's/jobs waiting: *0/&/2; t; p' file
```

Awk approach - use the return value of a `gsub`:

```
awk 'gsub(/jobs waiting: *0/,"&",$0) == 2' file
```

Invert as

```
awk 'gsub(/jobs waiting: *0/,"&",$0) != 2' file
```

(In all cases, `*0` allows for zero or more space characters before the `0`, consistent with your example.)

Comment: May I ask what is "KISS"?

Comment: @Tim [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Very nice! Sed using "grep-style" would be `sed -n '/jobs waiting: *0.*jobs waiting: *0/p' file` and `sed -n '/jobs waiting: *0.*jobs waiting: *0/!p' file`.

Comment: Or `grep -E '(jobs waiting: 0.*){2,}' file`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Cheers. (I think KISS stands for Keep IT Simple, Stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to get the desired lines as:

```
awk -F'jobs waiting: *0' 'NF > 2'
```

Where we split the records on the desired string, and should it  contain at least 2 instances of it, the number of fields will be 3 or more.

HTH